# Learning Curves - Entire dataset or only Training dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn

Can someone please explain if Learning Curves should be plotted using entire dataset (all X and all y) or just using Training dataset (X_train and y_train)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a regression problem: what you plot is the train accuracy (and also validation accuracy) on a plot accuracy vs. epoch.
So technically you use the entire dataset but you need to split it before, i.e. you use `(X_train, y_train)` and your validation dataset `(X_val, y_val)`.